# How can I check if a number has a - as its start value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tested the following code and it returned me false when I expected it to be true..How can I fix this and why it's returning me false?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var str3 ="-12346dsfs56";
var reg4 =/^(-{1})\d+$/;
alert(reg4.test(str3));
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex returns False because that string is not a number (it contains letters)!

If you drop the `$`, the regex will only check if the string begins with a `-` and at least one digit. And you can drop the `{1}`, it's unnecessary since one occurrence is the default for a regex token.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 simple ways i can think of.

first if its a number you can check if it's less than 0

```
if (number < 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

or in your case a string you can check if the first character is a `-`

```
if (str[0] == "-") {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Good to see a non-RegExp solution where it's not needed. But support for index access to strings is not universal (fails in IE), really should use *charAt(0)* or *substr(0,1)*.